# "401 Error Code" using google script app fetch post

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, fetch-api, http-status-code-401, urlfetch

Hi everyone recently i have been trying to do a fetch post in app script, from an api called salesbinder(inventory system), i have managed to fetch and pulls all inventory data down, however i have been struggling to post and add document to it and received an error code ->

> `"Truncated server response: {"message":"Unauthorized","url":"\/api\/2.0\/documents.json","code":401}"`

since I am using the same username and password I can assure that the details are correct for the authentication, would appreciate a lot if anyone could help me to solve the problem.

Here are the api documentaion (https://www.salesbinder.com/api/documents/add/) and the code i have been using.

```
  function posting(){
  var Username = "{API KEY}"
  var Password = "x"
  var headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(Username+ ':' + Password)
  };

  var url ='{API URL}'

  var data ={
    "document":{ 
      "customer_id": 'a93a9e9a-5837-4ec5-9dc7-47cc8cfd84e4',
      "issue_date":"2022-05-09",
      "context_id":5,
      "document_items":[  
          {  
              "quantity":2,
              "price":134,
              "item_id":"   b04993fe-7b17-42a1-b5e5-2d34890794c9"
          }
        ]
      },

    };

  var option = {
    "method": "post",
    'payload' : data,
    "headers": {headers},
  };


  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, option);
 

}
```

Comment: Looks like `headers` is already an object, so doing `"headers": headers,` could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your error message of `"message":"Unauthorized"` is due to `"headers": {headers},`. This has already been mentioned in [chrisg86's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72200991/401-error-code-using-google-script-app-fetch-post#comment127565444_72200991).

And also, from [this document](https://www.salesbinder.com/api/documents/), it seems that the request body is required to be sent with `Content-Type: application/json`.

#### From:

```js
var option = {
  "method": "post",
  'payload' : data,
  "headers": {headers},
};
```

#### To:

```js
var option = {
  "method": "post",
  "payload": JSON.stringify(data),
  headers, // or "headers": headers
  "contentType": "application/json"
};
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the values of `"Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(Username+ ':' + Password)`, `data` and `url` are correct. Please be careful this.